# get id's from file and store to txt

Tags: php

Normally i don't have access to test.php source, but i can view source(html) which shows id's.

In a href tag: http://localhost/details.php?id=**195320**

In test.php exist letters(link's): A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z these one corresponded to name and them description is consistently display/group them.

- Each letter viewed by: **test.php?letter=a** This page then contain 162 pages: **test.php?letter=a&page=1** (to 162)
- Another page (**letter=b**) contains 78 pages and so on (to letter z)

It's even possible with php get/extract id's from this file which shows data like that and store them in .txt file ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What've you tried?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you want to do. Maybe you need to be more clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Yes it is. You just need to query the webserver for each possibility and to extract the result. With which language do you want to do this?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm honestly, i didn't tryed anything because i don't have much experience in php or other programming language to do this.

Comment: @ZeroSuf3r: Try looking into web crawlers.

Comment: You'll need to parse the source HTML with DOM (http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), grab the anchor tags and their hrefs, then use `parse_url` and `parse_string` to break down the query string. It's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

i have find a tutorial for use file in php [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/files.php)

create file :

```
$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

write :

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

read :

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5);
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```